# Creating a three level inline ul in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using following HTML to create a three level inline list. First Level shows by default on page load. When I click on first level menu i.e. 'Courses' it expands and shows second level menus. But when I click on second level menus i.e. 'Computer Courses' or 'Civil Courses', they do not expand to show third level menus.

Thanks in advance for any help.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">          
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria- 
           haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Courses <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
           <li class="dropdown-submenu">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria- 
              haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" >Computer Courses<span class="caret"></span> 
              </a>
                 <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                     <li class="dropdown-submenu"><a href="#"><i class=" glyphicon glyphicon-menu- 
                       right"></i>IT Advance</a>
                     </li>
                     <li class="dropdown-submenu"><a href="#"><i class=" glyphicon glyphicon-menu- 
                      right"></i>Web Designing</a>
                     </li>
                 </ul>
           </li>
           <li class="dropdown-submenu">
             <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria- 
              haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Civil Courses<span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                 <li class="dropdown-submenu"><a href="#"><i class=" glyphicon glyphicon-menu- 
                   right"></i>Civil Survey</a>
                 </li>
                 <li class="dropdown-submenu"><a href="#"><i class=" glyphicon glyphicon-menu- 
                   right"></i>Quantity Survey</a>
                 </li>
              </ul>
          </li> 
     </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Please tag your Bootstrap version.

Comment: In bootstrap, you cannot implement multilevel dropdowns. It is a limitation in bootstrap. If you want to do such implementation either you have to make it custom or you can use https://mdbootstrap.com/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how twitter-bootstrap works exactly, but I can imagine having multiple `<a>` tags with `href="#"`s messes this up. Moreover, your html is not valid (you can have `<ul>` as a child of another `<ul>`) and perhaps wrapping a `<ul>` within an `<a>` is also not good practise.

Use javascript onclick functions for the expand behaviour, or dive a little deeper into twitter-bootstrap, in case they do support something like this.

P.S. Consult https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea to see what html is valid.